# Expose a webservice from existing web application

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, jboss6.x

I have below questions on my mind related to exposing a webservice.

1. We have existing web application based Spring MVC architecture, this
   application is deployed on Jboss server in the form of packaged war.
   There is access-manager-application which manages
   authentication/user management for application.
2. There is new requirement of exposing one of API of application as a web service. is it possible to expose webservice in existing war only? does spring support web application and webservice through same web.xml and context xml?
3. Or there should be different war itself and new domain? as existing domain is protected by access manager. will any possible expose of webservice from same domain will by pass access manager as it is going to be SOAP request?

I apologies for asking some basic questions.

Thanks..

Comment: you can use some existing frameworks like  Axis, Apache CXF to develop a webservice and once that is develop spring should take care of exposing it. Below is just an example for the reference https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Answer (score -1):

SOAP communication happens over HTTP. Hence, a web app will be able to handle it. As far as auth goes, you'll just have to adjust your auth config for the web service endpoints.

I'm sure you can find a lot of tutorials on how to build soap ws with spring mvc.

Comment: SOAP can also utilize other protocols than HTTP, f.e. SMTP, although this is not that common. Your comment should probably also include possible differences there could be between web applications and web/Rest services (session management, form-based vs. Authorization header vs. protocol extensions, ...) so the OP has a hint one what he might have to change in his current configuration. Furthermore, just mentioning that there are tutorials for SOAP-WS with Spring MVC is not worth an answer in my opinion

Comment: @RomanVottner I provided a simple answer to a simple question. You're over analyzing it in my opinion.